# How do I count multiple columns of events for users?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of events that stores the events for users and I want to get the number of two specific events for each user.

An example table is called "events" and it has 2 columns

```
user_id VARCHAR(50)
event_name VARCHAR(50)
```

The user_ids are all unique and the event names can be things like login, sent_message, liked_post

How do I, for example, query for the total messages sent per user AND the number of liked_posts per user?

Comment: If the `user_id` is unique as stated in your question, then the count for each user will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern of query you can use:

```
select user_id, 
    sent_message_count=sum(case when event_name = 'Sent Message' then 1 else 0 end), 
    liked_post_count=sum(case when event_name = 'Liked Post' then 1 else 0 end),
from events
group by user_id
```

Now, you just need to make sure the `when` part of each `case` statement fits the criteria you need.  The pattern itself - summing a bunch of 1's where the criteria fits, is really the key to achieving the result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, 
    SUM(IF(event_name = 'sent_message', 1, 0)) AS sent_message,  
    SUM(IF(event_name = 'liked_posts', 1, 0)) AS liked_posts
FROM `events`
GROUP BY user_id
```