# How do I find first event date for each user?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table of events that stores the events for users and I want to get the number of events for a user and also have the first event date in the result so that I can look at the data over time.

An example table is called "events" and it has 2 columns

```
user_id VARCHAR(50) 
event_name VARCHAR(50)
event_time TIMESTAMP
```

The user_ids are all unique and the event names can be things like login, sent_message, liked_post

How do I, for example, query for the total messages sent per user and also the time they first logged in which is the event_time of the first login for the user_id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count multiple columns of events for users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944845/how-do-i-count-multiple-columns-of-events-for-users)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Postgres 9.4 or later, you can use the `FILTER` clause to restrict what goes into your aggregates:

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        COUNT(event_time) FILTER (WHERE event_name = 'sent_message') AS messages_count,
        MIN(event_time) FILTER (WHERE event_name = 'login') AS first_login
FROM    events
GROUP BY user_id
```

Otherwise you can use `CASE`, but it is more verbose:

```
SELECT  user_id,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'sent_message' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS messages_count,
        MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'login' THEN event_time ELSE NULL END) AS first_login
FROM    events
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

`GROUP BY` and [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) are your friend here. Total messages sent per user:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(event_time) 
FROM table
WHERE event_name = 'sent_message'
GROUP BY user_id
```

First login:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(event_time) 
FROM table
WHERE event_name = 'login'
GROUP BY user_id
```